# How to use: PartCover .NET 4 with NUnit 2.5.6

Tags: .net, testing, nunit, code-coverage, partcover

Say I have Test assembly (NUnit compliant) App.Test.dll and a library to be tested App.dll.

How do I get the code coverage analysis using PartCover and NUint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I concur. In my experiments (see blog post here: http://www.csharpcity.com/using-partcover-and-nunit-for-code-coverage/) I set up a project with an NUnit-complaint "AutomatedTest" project (which referenced NUnit's framework DLL and outputted a DLL full of test classes), and ran that through PartCover.

Comment: I had a problem when I specified +[*]namespace* as the rule. +[Namespace]* works though

Comment: That's strange. The partcover doc swears that between square brackets is the project namespace. I start with +[*]* and then use whatever appears in the report :)

Comment: hmm when I tried +[*]* it reported the code coverage of nunit.. is there something I did wrong here?

Comment: I think you've already found my other thread on this. Yes, there seems to be a bug in PartCover.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to set up an NUnit test project (which runs App.Test.dll), then from PartCover call the NUnit console runner and pass the project name as a parameter.  I have a [blog post about it](http://relentlessdevelopment.wordpress.com/?s=partcover) if you want to check that out.

(I haven't tried with .Net 4 or the latest versions of NUnit/PartCover but I'm assuming it's still the same).

Answer (score 2):

It took me a while to figure out how get the source code markings. I had to put a /noshadow flag in the "Working Arguments". /noshadow prevents NUnit to make shadow copies of the files and will allow PartCover to load source files in the browser.

Then just click "Views->View Coverage Detail" after the run.